# C# Method errors: Unreachable code detected and not all code paths return a value”

Tags: c#

```
static class Util
{
    static Random ran = new Random();

    public static List<Point3d> RandomptGenerator(int num)
    {
        List <Point3d> ptList = new List<Point3d>();
        int count = num;

        for (int i = 0;i < count;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0;j < count;j++)
            {
                double x = i;
                double y = j;

                x = ran.Next(0, 40);
                y = ran.Next(0, 30);

                ptList.Add(new Point3d(x, y, 0.0));

                return ptList;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hi guys,

I am getting the following errors when I try to compile this code:

1. Unreachable code detected
2. not all code paths return a value

I cant figure out why this is happening... any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `return ptList;` should probably be at the end of the method

Comment: Look at where your return statement is

Answer (score 3):

In your code you are returning ptList inside the for loop. What will happen if count is 0 and you will never go inside the loop.

move  return ptList; outside of loop.

Answer (score 2):

The function is expected to return a List of Point3d objects. But there is no guarantee that the for loop conditions would be true (i < count) and the return statement would be reached at all. That's the reason why the compiler complains.

You should move the return statement outside of the loops as follows:

```
public static List<Point3d> RandomptGenerator(int num)
    {
        List<Point3d> ptList = new List<Point3d>();
        int count = num;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)

            {
                double x = i;
                double y = j;

                x = ran.Next(0, 40);
                y = ran.Next(0, 30);

                ptList.Add(new Point3d(x, y, 0.0));
            }
        }

        return ptList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function should return `List<Point3d>`. return it outside the loop

```
List<Point3d> ptList = new List<Point3d>();
int count = num;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        double x = i;
        double y = j;

        x = ran.Next(0, 40);
        y = ran.Next(0, 30);
        ptList.Add(new Point3d(x, y, 0.0));

    }

}
return ptList;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate `num` random points (please, notice that in your current code you create `num * num` points), all you have to do is

```
static class Util
{
    static Random ran = new Random();

    public static List<Point3d> RandomptGenerator(int num)
    {
      // Create list...
      List <Point3d> ptList = new List<Point3d>();

      // ...fill it with values...
      for (int i = 0;i < count; i++) 
          ptList.Add(new Point3d(ran.Next(0, 40), ran.Next(0, 30), 0.0));

      // ...return the list
      return ptList;   
   }
}
```

Often, we use *Linq* in order to generate the list for us:

```
using System.Linq

...

static class Util
{
    static Random ran = new Random();

    public static List<Point3d> RandomptGenerator(int num)
    {
      return Enumerable
        .Range(0, num)
        .Select(_ => new Point3d(ran.Next(0, 40), ran.Next(0, 30), 0.0))
        .ToList();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If "count" is 0, it wont even go in 1st for. because i =0 and i<0 is false.

Try like this:

```
    public static List<Point3d> RandomptGenerator(int num)
    {
        List<Point3d> ptList = new List<Point3d>();
        int count = num;


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)

        {
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)

            {
                double x = i;
                double y = j;

                x = ran.Next(0, 40);
                y = ran.Next(0, 30);

                ptList.Add(new Point3d(x, y, 0.0));
            }

        }

        return ptList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Should bE:

```
public static List<Point3d> RandomptGenerator(int num)
    {
      List <Point3d> ptList = new List<Point3d>();
      int count = num;

      for (int i = 0;i < count;i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0;j < count;j++)
        {
          double x = i;
          double y = j;

          x = ran.Next(0, 40);
          y = ran.Next(0, 30);

          ptList.Add(new Point3d(x, y, 0.0));

        }
      }
     return ptList;   //<------Must be here!
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the for loop.

It will not reach your return value.

If your value is less than zero.

**Ex.**

```
count =0;
for (int i = 0;i < count;i++) // the loop will end. when count is zero.
```

Same with your inner loop on :

```
count =0;
for (int j = 0;j < count;j++) // the loop will end. when count is zero.
```

So thats why you encountered an error

> > Unreachable code detected and not all code paths return a value

**You can fix it with this code:**

```
static Random ran = new Random();
public static List<Point3d> RandomptGenerator(int num)
{
  var <Point3d> ptList = new List<Point3d>();
  int count = num; 
  for (int i = 0;i < count;i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0;j < count;j++)
    {
      double x = i;
      double y = j;
      x = ran.Next(0, 40);
      y = ran.Next(0, 30);
      ptList.Add(new Point3d(x, y, 0.0));
    }
  }
  return ptList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect, the return ptList; was in the wrong position... that fixed the problem and obviously it makes sense.

Thank you everyone for your kind answers